# In Spark, can we assign an index to the JavaRDD<String> input?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to append my list of words with a doc ID so I know where the words come from. This is what I have at the start but it reads all the text from different files into a single string.

```
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFiles("mydir/*");
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile
.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
.mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
```

I tried using this to have a key and see whether I can merge the key into the values but the key is using path and I don't know how to continue.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> textFile = sc.wholeTextFiles("mydir");
```

I'm actually trying to get this key of output where hi, hello, hey are my words and the "-n" tells my which doc it is from

(hi-1)
(hello-2)
(hey-1)

but now it is showing

(hi-mydir/myfilename1.txt)
(hello-mydir/myfilename2.txt)
(hey-mydir/myfilename3.txt)

Comment: I don't really get your question.

Comment: hi @eliasah, I meant I'm actually trying to read all the files in "mydir" and tokenize them into words but I like to concatenate the words with -1, -2, -3... -n so I know the words belong to nth document.